# Replacing "Because"

Tags: word-choice

What could be a very good replacement of the word **because** in the following example without merging the two sentences? any appropriate Adverbial Clause?

> It is vital that universities equip our workforce with scientists, engineers and other professionals that enable our society to progress. **Because** a country without such experts is a country without the means to plan, create or maintain essential features of modern

Comment: "As" would work?

Comment: Considering the meaning of the quoted text, "because" seems the best. It might help if you give us more details, e.g. why you need a different word.

Comment: I actually have been told not to use Because at the beginning of a sentence. I don't remember the referencing. That's why bit confused. Will "This is because" improve the sentence?

Comment: Is this sentence made by You? Or is it taken from somewhere? From where? Ideally, the two sentences should be merged, and "because" is no longer at the beginning. However, it is OK, sometimes, to use that construct, to split the sentence in two parts and begin the second part with "because". As long as it does not become a habit.

Comment: Technically, having *because* at the start of this sentence can cause it to be read as not a sentence, as there is no principal verb - only the verb of a prepositional phrase. Such pseudo-sentences are fine informally, or in response to a question, but not in a non-dialogue formal context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that, for formal writing that isn't dialogue, you don't want to start a sentence with *because*. That means that what comes after is a prepositional phrase, and thus not a sentence. The quick fix, however, is to give the sentence a principal verb and a subject by using a relative pronoun:

> It is vital that universities equip our workforce with scientists, engineers and other professionals that enable our society to progress. **This is** because a country without such experts is a country without the means to plan, create or maintain essential features of modern

This isn't great, because some people will argue that *because...* can't be an object or a subject complement. However, you can put in an adjective to act as subject complement and let the *because...* be a prepositional phrase in a conventional way. The easy way is to find some alternative to *vital* that clearly refers back to *vital* but avoids repetition.

> It is vital that universities equip our workforce with scientists, engineers and other professionals that enable our society to progress. **This is essential** because a country without such experts is a country without the means to plan, create or maintain essential features of modern

---

I'm guessing you don't want to merge them because the second sentence looks like it goes on a bit past what you copied in here. If it doesn't produce a too huge sentence, and there's not other reason for the constraint, it's worth considering merging the sentences.